# Django ORM using cursor to memory optimize QuerySets

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, query-optimization, django-orm

Is there any way to convince Django ORM to use a database cursor when iterating through a large QuerySet so that it does not load all the objects at once but load them by parts instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .`iterator()` as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#iterator)

> Oracle and PostgreSQL use server-side cursors to stream results from
> the database without loading the entire result set into memory.